# Open CMD with the User Account Control (UAC) dialog

Tags: java, windows, javafx, elevated-privileges, elevation

I am working on a JavaFX project. At some point in the program I need to ask the user for elevated rights to perform a certain action.

How can I code this action?

My program is coded to work on Windows 10.

My program does not need any permission to work in the usual operation, only for this action is needed.

My program detects some devices that I have designed. The problem I have is that sometimes I need to change the VLAN ID of my network card. To do this I do it as follows:

```
public void VlanChanged (int vlanId) {
    StopDeviceSearch();
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String cmd = "cmd /c \"Echo S|powershell set-netadapter -InterfaceDescription 'Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller' -VlanID " + vlanId + "\"";
        rt.exec(cmd);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println (e);
    }
    RestarDeviceSearch();
}
```

If I run `myProject.jar` as administrator the above code works correctly, but if I don't run it as administrator the above code doesn't work.

Could I run my program and when the user activates the "VlanChanged" function that my program asks the user for administrator permissions to run CMD as administrator and be able to perform the VLAN ID change action correctly?

I have tried with the command

```
"runas /profile /user: Administrator"
```

but it doesn't work.

I would like the Windows banner to be opened that asks you:

"Do you want to allow this application to make changes to the device?"

That the window has the title: "User Account Control".

I have been searching and I just want the "UAC dialog".

Comment: I don't know why my question is getting closed?!?!

Comment: Consider using class `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`. Run `powershell.exe` directly. No need for `cmd.exe`. Look at the `powershell.exe` [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1). Maybe you can run a script file that first asks the user for elevated rights and then executes your desired command.